# Difference between Primary GIC vs Secondary GIC in ARM

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cortex-a8

As per the kernel documentation of gic device tree bindings

"Primary GIC is attached directly to the CPU and typically has PPIs and SGIs."

"Secondary GICs are cascaded into the upward interrupt controller and do not
have PPIs or SGIs."

I do not find the term primary/secondary GIC in GIC-400. 
Can anyone please describe the difference or point to the document which tell something about it.

Answer (score 4):

The terminology *Primary* and *Secondary* is Linux terminology.  You will not find it in an ARM data sheet.  The **PPIs** are banked per-CPU.  The code can execute on any *CPU*, so only the extra interrupts maybe set.  I think this is rather *pedantic* as most systems will only have one controller.

> Find out how many interrupts are supported. 
>     The GIC only supports up to 1020 interrupt sources.

This comes from allocation of the *address space* on the controller.  There is only *decode* room to fit 1020 external interrupts.  Note, the define `CONFIG_GIC_NON_BANKED` and the note *Frankein-GIC without banked registers...*  It is most normal that in an **SMP-ARM** that the GIC will service all cores.  The variable `gic_nr` tracks the number of controllers.  If you have more that 1020 interrupt sources, you need another controller.

> Can anyone please describe the difference?

The primary will service the **PPIs**.  The **PPI** exist on the 2<sup>nd</sup> controller, but they are redundant.  The 2<sup>nd</sup> (and higher) controllers are just for external interrupts.

Comment: **PPI** stands for *peripheral private interrupt*, for those who don't have the datasheet handy; typically used for CPU specific interrupts like per-core watchdog, timer, etc.  Other interrupt sources are global to all CPUs.